# Regexp: What's the difference between these 4 expressions

Tags: regex

Trying to learn regexp but got confused about the syntax. How would these different expressions differ? :

```
([A-Z]){3}
([A-Z]{3})
[A-Z]{3}
[A-Z]\3 edit: meant ([A-Z])\3
```

Answer (score 2):

- `([A-Z]){3}` - matches 3 uppercase letters, there will be 3 groups
- `([A-Z]{3})` - matches 3 uppercase letters into one group
- `[A-Z]{3}` - matches 3 uppercase letters, no grouping
- `[A-Z]\3` - should be an invalid regex in most languages (matches one uppercase letter and a backreference to group 3) e.g. `([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])\3` would matche 2 uppercase letters and another uppercase letter that occurs two times

Comment: Mistyped the last one. Meant ([A-Z])\3

Comment: @r.r this won't change much, as it is still an invalid backrefernce

Answer (score 2):

`([A-Z]){3}` - This matches three capture groups, with each containing letters from A-Z

`([A-Z]{3})` - This is the same as above, but it encloses all three letteres in a single capture group

`[A-Z]{3}` - This matches letters from A-Z three times, with no capture group

`[A-Z]\3` - This matches a single character from A-Z followed by `\3` (at least in Java)

You might be wondering what a "capture group" is.  It is a way of keeping track of things which matched during the course of evaluating your regular expression.  For example, consider your first regex:

```
([A-Z]){3}
```

which is equivalent to

```
([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])
```

If you evaluated this regex, then, in Java for example, you would be able to access each of the three matched letters using the variables `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

Comment: And usually the best approach is to see it yourself: [one](https://regex101.com/r/aC0rS0/1) matches `C` in `ABCDEFG`, [two](https://regex101.com/r/aC0rS0/2) will match `ABC` in `ABCDEFGH` and [three](https://regex101.com/r/aC0rS0/3) matches the same as **two** but does not provide any capture groups.

Comment: The fourth expalantion is not always correct - it will match `A-Z` and tries then to find a backreference to the third subpattern (which is not there, so the expression will fail).

Comment: @Jan I tested the fourth expression in Java, and it _did_ match the sequence `A\3`.  So, at least in Java, my explanation is correct.